# Incrementing [i] in the for-loop does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

this seems to be a simple question and I hope you can help me.
I'd like to add that my code works the way I'm describing it. I'm not content with the way I solved my problem concerning my problem in incrementing [i] outside the for-loop.

What I want is to get a sidebar menu shown when one hovers over an image.

My CSS looks like:

```
GM_addStyle
(
'.colormenu {       \
 display:none;      \
 margin-left: 10px;     \
 margin-top: -55px;     \
 }              \
 .colormenu a {         \
 display: block;                \
 width: 30px;                   \
 }                          \
 .colorlist {                   \
 list-style-type: none;         \
 }                          \
'
);
```

Now I'm defining two variables. One containing some colors, the other containing some fruits.

```
var color = ['red','yellow','green','blue'];
var fruit = ['strawberry','banana','apple','blueberry'];
```

I then define two arrays:

```
var hoverstring = new Array(color.length);
var idstring = new Array(color.length);
```

Now I want to see whether the value of an element of var color matches a title of the images on the webiste.
For every element being smaller than the length of var color I create two links in a list being wrapped by a div and insert it after a href wrapping the img-element.

```
for (var i=0;i<color.length;i++) {
 $("<div id='colormenu"+i+"' class='colormenu'><ul class='colorlist'><li><a href='path"+color[i]+"'>Call</a></li><li><a href='path"+color[i]+"'>Chat</a></li></ul><div>").insertAfter("a[href$='"+fruit[i]+"']"); 


 hoverstring[i]="img[title$='"+fruit[i]+"']:first";
 idstring[i]="#colormenu"+i;

}
```

The last step I take and this is where I got problems with is to create a function for every element. This is just an example of what it looks like:

```
    $(hoverstring[0]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[0]).toggle();
    });

    $(hoverstring[1]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[1]).toggle();
    });

    $(hoverstring[2]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[2]).toggle();
    });

    $(hoverstring[3]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[3]).toggle();
    });

    $(hoverstring[4]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[4]).toggle();
    });

    $(hoverstring[5]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[5]).toggle();
    });
```

This method works, but is not very handy I'd say. Instead of creating a high amount of functions I'd like to increment i and not do it manually.

Like:

```
for (var i=0;i<color.length;i++) {
 $("<div id='colormenu"+i+"' class='colormenu'><ul class='colorlist'><li><a href='path"+color[i]+"'>Call</a></li><li><a href='path"+color[i]+"'>Chat</a></li></ul><div>").insertAfter("a[href$='"+fruit[i]+"']");




 hoverstring[i]="img[title$='"+fruit[i]+"']:first";
 idstring[i]="#colormenu"+i;


$(hoverstring[i]).hover(function(){
        $(idstring[i]).toggle();
    });
}
```

I tried it several times, but for some reason i isn't incremented in the for-loop. Have you got an idea why?

I really hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something quick like this:

```
$.each(color, function(i) {
  $("<div id='colormenu"+i+"' class='colormenu'><ul class='colorlist'><li><a href='path"+this+"'>Call</a></li><li><a href='path"+this+"'>Chat</a></li></ul><div>").insertAfter("a[href$='"+fruit[i]+"']");
  $("img[title$='"+fruit[i]+"']:first").hover(function(){
    $("#colormenu"+i).toggle();
  });
});
```

The difference here is that `i` is scoped to this callback, not referencing the same variable that's changing with the loop each time.

Comment: That's just brilliant. Would have take me days to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, congratulations on reaching 100K!

Answer (score 2):

You're facing one of biggest mistakes a `ECMA-/ Javascript` programmer can make:

Forgetting about `closures` and `hoisting of variables`.

Putting this in your `for-loop`:

```
$(hoverstring[i]).hover(function(){
    $(idstring[i]).toggle();
});
```

would cause that `i` would be closured by all of your methods. You need to invoke another function to solve that issue:

```
for (var i=0;i<color.length;i++) {
   $("<div id='colormenu"+i+"' class='colormenu'><ul class='colorlist'><li><a        href='path"+color[i]+"'>Call</a></li><li><a        href='path"+color[i]+"'>Chat</a></li></ul><div>").insertAfter("a[href$='"+fruit[i]+"']"); 


   hoverstring[i]="img[title$='"+fruit[i]+"']:first";
   idstring[i]="#colormenu"+i;

   (function(index){
       $(hoverstring[index]).hover(function(){
          $(idstring[index]).toggle();
       });
   }(i));
}
```

Comment: What can I say than the biggest 'Thank You' I've got. I'm not a programmer, just trying to understand the syntax and trying to learn every day a little bit more. Thanks for pointing out my mistake and everything.

Answer (score 2):

It is incrementing `i` just fine, but the `i` inside your hover function is a *reference* to the `i` in the loop. After the loop is complete, the `i` inside the hover function, inside *all* hover functions, is the value of `i` after the loop. This is called a closure.

If you want to freeze the value of `i` at the specific point in time you create the function, you need to do this:

```
$(hoverstring[i]).hover((function (x) {
    return function () {
        $(idstring[x]).toggle();
    }
})(i));
```